# google api python client wrong folder authorized

Tags: python-3.x, google-api-python-client

I am automatically downloading file from gdrive, works great BUT authorized wrong path (wrong gdrive and folder) on this one computer when it runs you through the automatic authorization. Any idea how to get the api to reauthorize for the correct drive/folder? Super newbie so apologies if this is worded confusingly. (folder paths changes for confidentiality i guess)
Code used for initial authorization:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

"""Initial comment."""

import datetime
import io
# import mimetypes
import os
import shutil
import time
import hashlib
import httplib2


# from os import path
from googleapiclient import discovery
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import tools
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload

# import initial_upload

# If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
# at ~/.credentials/drive-python-quickstart.json
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret.json'
APPLICATION_NAME = 'Drive Sync'

# Declare full path to folder and folder name
FULL_PATH = r'PATH WAS HERE'
DIR_NAME = 'Data'
# Or simply
#DIR_NAME = FULL_PATH.split('/')[-1]

# Sample (reference) map of Google Docs MIME types to possible exports
# (for more information check about().get() method with exportFormats field)
GOOGLE_MIME_TYPES = {
    'application/vnd.google-apps.document':
    ['application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
     '.docx'],
    # 'application/vnd.google-apps.document':
    # 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text',
    'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet':
    ['application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
     '.xlsx'],
    # 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet',
    'application/vnd.google-apps.presentation':
    ['application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation',
     '.pptx']
    # 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation'
}
# 'application/vnd.google-apps.drawing': 'application/x-msmetafile'
# 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder': '',
# 'application/vnd.google-apps.form': 'application/pdf',
# 'application/vnd.google-apps.fusiontable': '',
# 'application/vnd.google-apps.map': 'application/pdf',
# 'application/vnd.google-apps.photo': 'image/jpeg',
# 'application/vnd.google-apps.file': '',
# 'application/vnd.google-apps.sites': '',
# 'application/vnd.google-apps.unknown': '',
# 'application/vnd.google-apps.video': '',
# 'application/vnd.google-apps.audio': '',
# 'application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk': ''
# 'application/octet-stream': 'text/plain'

def folder_upload(service):
    '''Uploads folder and all it's content (if it doesnt exists)
    in root folder.

    Args:
        items: List of folders in root path on Google Drive.
        service: Google Drive service instance.

    Returns:
        Dictionary, where keys are folder's names
        and values are id's of these folders.
    '''

    parents_id = {}

    for root, _, files in os.walk(FULL_PATH, topdown=True):
        last_dir = root.split('/')[-1]
        pre_last_dir = root.split('/')[-2]
        if pre_last_dir not in parents_id.keys():
            pre_last_dir = []
        else:
            pre_last_dir = parents_id[pre_last_dir]

        folder_metadata = {'name': last_dir,
                           'parents': [pre_last_dir],
                           'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'}
        create_folder = service.files().create(body=folder_metadata,
                                               fields='id').execute()
        folder_id = create_folder.get('id', [])

        for name in files:
            file_metadata = {'name': name, 'parents': [folder_id]}
            media = MediaFileUpload(
                os.path.join(root, name),
                mimetype=mimetypes.MimeTypes().guess_type(name)[0])
            service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                   media_body=media,
                                   fields='id').execute()

        parents_id[last_dir] = folder_id

    return parents_id


def check_upload(service):
    """Checks if folder is already uploaded,
    and if it's not, uploads it.

    Args:
        service: Google Drive service instance.

    Returns:
        ID of uploaded folder, full path to this folder on computer.

    """

    results = service.files().list(
        pageSize=100,
        q="'root' in parents and trashed != True and \
        mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'").execute()

    items = results.get('files', [])

    # Check if folder exists, and then create it or get this folder's id.
    if DIR_NAME in [item['name'] for item in items]:
        folder_id = [item['id']for item in items
                     if item['name'] == DIR_NAME][0]
    else:
        parents_id = folder_upload(service)
        folder_id = parents_id[DIR_NAME]

    return folder_id, FULL_PATH


def get_credentials():
    """Gets valid user credentials from storage.

    If nothing has been stored, or if the stored credentials are invalid,
    the OAuth2 flow is completed to obtain the new credentials.

    Returns:
        Credentials, the obtained credential.
    """
    home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
    credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
    if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
        os.makedirs(credential_dir)
    credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir,
                                   'drive-python-sync.json')

    store = Storage(credential_path)
    credentials = store.get()
    if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
        flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
        # if flags:
        credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags=None)
        # else:  # Needed only for compatibility with Python 2.6
        # credentials = tools.run(flow, store)
        print('Storing credentials to ', credential_path)
    return credentials


def get_tree(folder_name, tree_list, root, parents_id, service):
    """Gets folder tree relative paths.

    Recursively gets through subfolders, remembers their names ad ID's.

    Args:
        folder_name: Name of folder, initially
        name of parent folder string.
        folder_id: ID of folder, initially ID of parent folder.
        tree_list: List of relative folder paths, initially
        empy list.
        root: Current relative folder path, initially empty string.
        parents_id: Dictionary with pairs of {key:value} like
        {folder's name: folder's Drive ID}, initially empty dict.
        service: Google Drive service instance.

    Returns:
        List of folder tree relative folder paths.

    """
    folder_id = parents_id[folder_name]

    results = service.files().list(
        pageSize=100,
        q=("%r in parents and \
        mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'and \
        trashed != True" % folder_id)).execute()

    items = results.get('files', [])
    root += folder_name + os.path.sep

    for item in items:
        parents_id[item['name']] = item['id']
        tree_list.append(root + item['name'])
        folder_id = [i['id'] for i in items
                     if i['name'] == item['name']][0]
        folder_name = item['name']
        get_tree(folder_name, tree_list,
                 root, parents_id, service)


def download_file_from_gdrive(file_path, drive_file, service):
    """Downloads file from Google Drive.

    If file is Google Doc's type, then it will be downloaded
    with the corresponding non-Google mimetype.

    Args:
        path: Directory string, where file will be saved.
        file: File information object (dictionary), including it's name, ID
        and mimeType.
        service: Google Drive service instance.
    """
    file_id = drive_file['id']
    file_name = drive_file['name']
    if drive_file['mimeType'] in GOOGLE_MIME_TYPES.keys():
        if file_name.endswith(GOOGLE_MIME_TYPES[drive_file['mimeType']][1]):
            file_name = drive_file['name']
        else:
            file_name = '{}{}'.format(
                drive_file['name'],
                GOOGLE_MIME_TYPES[drive_file['mimeType']][1])
            service.files().update(fileId=file_id,
                                   body={'name': file_name}).execute()


        request = service.files().export(
            fileId=file_id,
            mimeType=(GOOGLE_MIME_TYPES[drive_file['mimeType']])[0]).execute()
        with io.FileIO(os.path.join(file_path, file_name), 'wb') as file_write:
            file_write.write(request)

    else:
        request = service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
        file_io = io.FileIO(os.path.join(file_path, drive_file['name']), 'wb')
        downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(file_io, request)
        done = False
        while done is False:
            _, done = downloader.next_chunk()


def by_lines(input_str):
    """Helps Sort items by the number of slashes in it.

    Returns:
        Number of slashes in string.
    """
    return input_str.count(os.path.sep)


def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Google Drive API.

    Creates a Google Drive API service object and outputs the names and IDs
    for up to 10 files.
    """
    # credentials = get_credentials()
    http = get_credentials().authorize(httplib2.Http())
    service = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=http)

    # Get id of Google Drive folder and it's path (from other script)
    # folder_id, full_path = initial_upload.check_upload(service)
    folder_id, full_path = check_upload(service)
    folder_name = full_path.split(os.path.sep)[-1]
    tree_list, root, parents_id = [], '', {}

    # About_drive = service.about().get(
    # fields='importFormats, exportFormats').execute()
    # print(About_drive)
    parents_id[folder_name] = folder_id
    get_tree(folder_name, tree_list, root, parents_id, service)
    os_tree_list = []
    root_len = len(full_path.split(os.path.sep)[0:-2])

    # Get list of folders three paths on computer
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(full_path, topdown=True):
        for name in dirs:
            var_path = (os.path.sep).join(
                root.split(os.path.sep)[root_len + 1:])
            os_tree_list.append(os.path.join(var_path, name))

    # old folders on computer
    download_folders = list(set(tree_list).difference(set(os_tree_list)))
    # new folders on computer, which you dont have(i suppose heh)
    remove_folders = list(set(os_tree_list).difference(set(tree_list)))
    # foldes that match
    exact_folders = list(set(os_tree_list).intersection(set(tree_list)))

    exact_folders.append(folder_name)

    var = (os.path.sep).join(full_path.split(os.path.sep)[0:-1]) + os.path.sep

    # Download folders from Drive
    download_folders = sorted(download_folders, key=by_lines)

    for folder_dir in download_folders:
        variable = var + folder_dir
        last_dir = folder_dir.split(os.path.sep)[-1]

        folder_id = parents_id[last_dir]
        results = service.files().list(
            pageSize=20, q=('%r in parents' % folder_id)).execute()

        items = results.get('files', [])
        os.makedirs(variable)
        files = [f for f in items
                 if f['mimeType'] != 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder']

        for drive_file in files:
            # file_id = f['id']
            download_file_from_gdrive(variable, drive_file, service)

    # Check and refresh files in existing folders
    for folder_dir in exact_folders:
        # var = '/'.join(full_path.split('/')[0:-1]) + '/'
        variable = var + folder_dir
        last_dir = folder_dir.split(os.path.sep)[-1]
        os_files = [f for f in os.listdir(variable)
                    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(variable, f))]
        folder_id = parents_id[last_dir]

        results = service.files().list(
            pageSize=1000,
            q=('%r in parents and \
            mimeType!="application/vnd.google-apps.folder"' % folder_id),
            fields="files(id, name, mimeType, \
                modifiedTime, md5Checksum)").execute()

        items = results.get('files', [])

        refresh_files = [f for f in items if f['name'] in os_files]
        upload_files = [f for f in items if f['name'] not in os_files]
        remove_files = [f for f in os_files
                        if f not in [j['name']for j in items]]

        for drive_file in refresh_files:
            file_dir = os.path.join(variable, drive_file['name'])
            file_time = os.path.getmtime(file_dir)
            # mtime = drive_file['modifiedTime']
            mtime = datetime.datetime.strptime(drive_file['modifiedTime'][:-2],
                                               "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")
            drive_time = time.mktime(mtime.timetuple())

            file_dir = os.path.join(variable, drive_file['name'])
            os_file_md5 = hashlib.md5(open(file_dir, 'rb').read()).hexdigest()
            if 'md5Checksum' in drive_file.keys():
                # print(1, file['md5Checksum'])
                drive_md5 = drive_file['md5Checksum']
                # print(2, os_file_md5)
            else:
                drive_md5 = None

            if (file_time < drive_time) or (drive_md5 != os_file_md5):
                os.remove(os.path.join(variable, drive_file['name']))
                download_file_from_gdrive(variable, drive_file, service)

        for os_file in remove_files:
            os.remove(os.path.join(variable, os_file))

        for drive_file in upload_files:
            download_file_from_gdrive(variable, drive_file, service)

    # Delete old and unwanted folders from computer
    remove_folders = sorted(remove_folders, key=by_lines, reverse=True)

    for folder_dir in remove_folders:
        # var = '/'.join(full_path.split('/')[0:-1]) + '/'
        variable = var + folder_dir
        last_dir = folder_dir.split(os.path.sep)[-1]
        shutil.rmtree(variable)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: That's a lot of code - are you sure it's just the "code used for initial authorization" and not your entire script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: SOLVED! You just need to reset the credentials located:

C:\Users\ [Your User] \.credentials\drive-python-sync.json

Delete that file and it will need to reauthorize any working path so you can reset or choose the correct drive/file again.

Thank you to tehhowch for trying to help!